# matlab add text with imread

Tags: matlab, imshow

I have a series of images that I am creating a movie loop with. The code looks like the following:

```matlab
path1 = '/path/to/data';
dir1 = dir(path1);

writerObj = VideoWriter('video.avi');
writerObj.FrameRate = 10;
writerObj.Quality = 100;
open(writerObj);

for i = 3:length(dir1)
    filename = [path1,'/',dir1(i).name];
    timee= dir2(i).name(29:43);
    thisimage = imread(filename);
    writeVideo(writerObj, thisimage);
end
close(writerObj);
```

I would like to add a text based on the 'time' variable created, which is simply a string of 'YYYYMMDD-HHMMSS'. I know this can be done with:

```matlab
imshow(thisimage);
text(300,500,timee, 'Color','white','FontSize',20);
```

but when put in the loop above, it just simply creates a new figure with the text instead of embedding it in the image.

Therefore, how do I add the text in the image and include it in the movie loop? NOTE: I do not have access to the Computer Vision System Toolbox (therefore, I cannot use the 'insertText' function)

Comment: It still creates a new figure, so no unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

Your basic approach is correct, but the image+text is not getting passed to writeVideo. The trick is to use [`getframe`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) to get it into the expected format. Modify your `for` loop as follows:

```
for i = 3:length(dir1)
    filename = [path1,'/',dir1(i).name];
    timee= dir2(i).name(29:43);
    thisimage = imread(filename);

    imshow(thisimage);                                  % Load image to figure
    text(300,500,timee, 'Color','white','FontSize',20); % Add text to figure
    writeVideo(writerObj, getframe(gcf));               % Add figure to video
    close(gcf);                                         % Close the figure window
end
```